# Azure Lifecycle Management Rule

Tags: azure, migration, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to set up an Azure Lifecycle Management rule.  I want to move my active/Hot files/blobs that are over 90 days old to an Archive tier. I tried walking through the Lifecycle Management wizard but when I come to the If/Then screen where you identify that the blobs that are 90 days old should be moved, the `Then` drop-down only allows `Delete the blob`. Do I have to somehow activate the Archive/Cold Storage tier in order to have `Move to Archive` option available in the dropdown?

Comment: What kind of storage account you have?

Comment: StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you select "Append blobs" in blob types (1st step) because access tier is only available for Block blobs.

[image]

Furthermore, please ensure that the redundancy type for your storage account is one of the following values: LRS, GRS, or RA-GRS. Archive tier is not supported for ZRS, GZRS, or RA-GZRS.

[image]

Please make sure that these conditions are met. To learn more, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: I read the article, I find it odd that you cannot archive append blobs. What does it matter, the blob type? Is there an approach to archiving append blobs?

Comment: You’ll need to ask storage team for tiering only supported for block blobs.

Comment: So, in order to archive my growing list of append blobs, I would have to convert them to block blobs?

Comment: In a way, yes. But you can’t change the blob type so what you have to do is download these blobs and upload them as block blobs.